# Firebase firestore can't save data. No exception

Tags: firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

Can anyone help me?

i try to save a doc on to firestore, but that does not seem to work, also there's no Exception.

I'm using Ionic 3

```
saveUserOnDatabase(user: firebase.User){

let usuario: Usuario = new Usuario();
usuario.id = user.uid
usuario.nome = user.displayName
usuario.photoUrl = user.photoURL

const firestore = firebase.firestore()
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true}
firestore.settings(settings)
firestore.collection("user_data").doc(usuario.id).set(usuario)
.then( resp => {console.log("dados do usuario gravados no banco" + resp)})
.catch( error => {console.log("deu erro no banco" + error)})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you arent getting an error message but I know that you cant set a document equal to your custom class right now. I put a function on my class's that just returns a generic object. e.g.

```
export class Usuario {
    id: string;
    nome: string;
    photoUrl: string;
    getData(data): object {
        const result = {};
        Object.keys(data).map(key => result[key] = data[key]);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then in your code you would do this

```
firestore.collection("user_data").doc(usuario.id).set(usuario.getData())
```